# StreamWriter collisions in C# Backend Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am having an issue opening a log file on my ASP.NET backend process (C#) when i have multiple calls at the sametime. Getting error: file is open by another process

From what I understand of IIS it is a single worker process using multiple threads.

If true can I assume that if I were to use a lock() I can avoid this when opening the same file to write data by eaiting for all previous threads to exit the file?

My IIS site makes multiple calls (maybe from same or different user) to a backend function that opens the same logfile.. if I were to use a lock could I simply wait until the file was not used and write to it?

Thanks

Comment: Writing to a file probably isn't the best approach for a multi-user environment in the first place.  Why not write to a database instead?

Comment: Which type of DB would you suggest for a simple logfile?

Comment: I imagine any database could be used to store data.  Given you're using Microsoft technologies already, SQL Server Express seems like a reasonable place to start.

Comment: _Use. A. Logging Framework._ Yes, you need to configure it and change code. But you probably have already spent more time on this problem than you would have on just adopting a logging framework.

Comment: Side note: @Fildor's suggestion is only useful if OP is doing something for real (in production). There is no indication that the code they trying to write is to be used for anything but personal entertainment/education - indeed writing custom logging framework is a traditional (and somewhat important) step in learning programming...